# Importing DXF/DWG file without losing extra attribute information

Tags: qgis, import, dxf, autocad-map

**Let me be clear here I know how to import a DWG/DXF file here the problem lies that there is extra data that gets lost**. One layer in particular is what we want to import the Layer XXX and separate into four different shapefiles based on the EVAL parameter. The problem is that when we import the DXF file with the features, the extra data gets lost, it is not available in the attribute table.

Picture of the data:

**I have all object selected here to "Censor" the data.**

[image]

How do we solve this?

Comment: I remember i have had the same problem with a dwg, and i use "ODA File Converter". I'm not sure, but i think the solution was to convert to ascii dxf.

Comment: ACAD has something called "spatial manager", this should help you - you directly export a `.shp` by using it.

Comment: Okay how do I use this spatial manager?

Comment: You can export by ACAD-Map into shapefiles with your extended attributes, than use your data in QGIS.

Comment: Just FYI the default dxf/dwg export from QGIS does not create block attributes. You'll need another tool or software. SpatialManager plugin for AutoCAD, AutoCAD Map 3D, ArcGIS, FME, etc. Note you can't even use SpatialManager for LT. The only free alternative I have come across is an ancient, clunky tool from 1997 called dxfAuthor.

Comment: This is not a problem, we usually export it by DATAEXTRACTION with X and Y data and then manual link it based on those X and Y coordinates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Autocad map Solution: Export your data by autocad Map Output -> Map data transfer, or just run **mapexport** in command line and choose the format ESRI shapefile as Export file. In the new table select all your features that you wanna export and switch to Data section.
Into select attributes you will find your object data table in the list, all you have to do is checking that table and anything else in properties that you want to have into shapefiles.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use Data Extraction in CAD to create a CSV file with Positions X,Y and whatever attributes you want. That will import into QGIS.